# How to convert part of a character array to a integer variable in C

Tags: c, arrays, input, char

I have a assignment in which I am supposed to take in a user's input in the form of:

```
double, char('C' for Celsius or 'F' for Fahrenheit)
```

and convert it into the other temp scale. To do this task, I wrote this program:

## The Program

```
/*
  The purpose of these program is to convert a user's input and use it in a tempurate conversion programs.
  By Paramjot Singh

  Psuedocode:

  import all needed files

  ask for user's input.

  convert user's imput into 2 varibles: a double and a char

  if the char is 'c' convert the double to farinhiet
  if the char is 'c' convert the double to celius

  display the result.
*/

 #include <stdio.h>
 int main( )
 {
    char input[7];
    printf("Welcome to the Tempurate Conversion Enter a number followed by C or F, depending on if you what to convert a Celuis Temp to Farinheit or vice versa.");
    fgets(input, 7, stdin);
    /*if (in == 'C' || in == 'c') commnented out code
    {
        int f = 9 / 5 (inint + 32);
        printf("Input ", in, " Output: " f, " F");
    }
     else (inint == 'F' || inint == 'f')
    {
        int c = 5 / 9 (inint - 32);
        printf("Input ", in, " Output: " c, " C");
    }
     else 
    {
       printf("I told you to enter c or f. Restart the program.");
    } */

     /*to test what was entered*/
     printf(input);
     return 0;
}
```

My question is what would I do to convert part of the character array to a double.

Comment: Why not simply `scanf("%lf,%c",&inint,&in);` ?

Comment: What format is the input supposed to be? I'm assuming, e.g., "30F" but you didn't say. All of the suggestions so far assume that the input has a comma.

Comment: @P0W Because one should not use `scanf()`.

Comment: Blanket statements like "don't use scanf" without reasons or alternatives are not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Per the printf statement:

```
printf("Welcome to the Tempurate Conversion Enter a number followed by C or F, depending on if you what to convert a Celuis Temp to Farinheit or vice versa.");
```

It looks like you expect the user to enter (for example): 23.5c

This implies a: `scanf("%lf%c", &inDouble, &inChar);` statement with NO intervening comma.` Note the change to the variable names.

Also, the `tolower(inChar)` will simplify some of your if logic.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 but you forgot to mention that `fgets()` and `strtod()` should be used instead of `scanf()`. Also, why not `inDouble`, if we are scanning `double`s?

Comment: Will edit the variables name.  There is nothing wrong with `scanf()` when used as directed.

Comment: @H2CO3 i guess everyone can have an opinion, but it certainly is NOT deprecated and new programmers writing console i/o will always use it.  So, we might as well teach them how to use it correctly.

Comment: I never said it was deprecated!

Comment: @H2CO3, I did NOT mean to imply that you did.

Comment: @H2CO3: `scanf` doesn't strike me as especially heinous. What's the worst thing about it?

Comment: @nneonneo It doesn't do what you think it does (more precisely, its usage is unintuitive, such as stopping at the first whitespace when scanning a string), and it's also unsafe (again, unless you specify an explicit field width, `%s` can overrun your buffers, etc.)

Comment: @H2CO3: The first one isn't particularly surprising given that `scanf` was designed for field-separated data (use `fgets` for lines). `%s` overrunning your buffers is definitely a problem that is too easy to make, so I'll accept that.

Answer (score 0):

Scan your input with [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/):

```
sscanf(input, "%lf, %c", &inint, &in);
```

**Edit:** `inint` is a bit of a misleading name. You're supposed to read in a double, right?